# Did Picard get in trouble when he was in command of the Stargazer and lost his ship?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-the-next-generation

I always wondered if the gap between his time as Captain of the Stargazer and Captain of the Enterprise was because he was barred from captaincy.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the Season 2 episode *The Measure Of A Man*, we learn that Picard had been brought to a court martial over the loss of the Stargazer, but that he was absolved of any and all charges brought at that time. So, he was briefly in trouble - but not in a career limiting way.

From the TV shows and movies, we don't have any clear indication of what Picard did between the Stargazer incident (Battle of Maxia) in 2355 and his taking command of the Enterprise in 2364. There is one hint that he may have been in command of another ship in the season 4 episode *Legacy*, as he describes his first encounter with Tasha Yar and mentions "his ship" responding to a distress call. Other than that, the shows are silent on these nine years.

There is an expanded universe novel, *The Buried Age*, that covers this gap and also provides some more details about the Battle of Maxia. After the court martial Picard returns to archaeology and takes a break from command. At some point he returns to a desk job at Starfleet, and finally applies for command again and is granted command of the Enterprise.

Comment: Out-of-universe, I believe it's standard practice for any naval captain that loses his vessel to undergo a court martial to ascertain the facts of the case. It does not indicate he was believed to be at fault.

Comment: @Darren, that's awesome to know.  I always have to remind myself just how much Star Trek chain of command is modeled on naval forces and maritime law

Comment: @Darren you appear to be correct from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Court-martial : "Most navies have a standard court-martial which convenes whenever a ship is lost; this does not presume that the captain is suspected of wrongdoing, but merely that the circumstances surrounding the loss of the ship be made part of the official record."

Comment: @Sam, I often am :)

Comment: @Darren Is this only done in cases of non-combat loss of ship?  Because I'd imagine that ships which go down in battle would be somewhat commonplace, at least back in the days when ship-to-ship combat was more common than it is today.  If you're fighting a major war, you might not have time to court-martial every captain that loses a ship...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman My understanding is that it's in all cases, but don't quote me.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman if Patrick O'Brien's well-researched Napoleonic novels are any evidence, this was historical practice for combat losses as well--have to make sure that the combat was carried out competently & without cowardice. (Not to mention it's a good opportunity for Monday-morning quarterbacking and settling political scores.) OTOH, modern USN practice is a Board of Inquiry which may or may not lead to a court martial (see USS Indianapolis and Charles McVay III). I think the BoI was introduced in the late 19th century & would've been a court-martial prior, but not 100% sure there.

Comment: Seems like a big jump from the Stargazer to the Enterprise, the Federation flag ship. You would assume be did something between the two to merit such a post.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman then you [drumhead that court-martial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drumhead_court-martial) right then and there, even as you watch it burn. Drumheads aren't so bad when everyone goes into it knowing acquittal is the certain outcome.

Comment: @user There's a few oddities about Picard's career - 22 years as the commanding officer of a single ship, for one thing.